# Excluding posts not working

Tags: posts, categories, exclude

I have tried a lot but didn't got a proper result. Someone please check my code, where I am doing mistake.

I want to show other posts with same categories but not the post shows on single page also previous and next post of the current post. Is there any other way to show?

```
$thisid = get_the_ID();
$prevpost = get_previous_post();
$previd = $prevpost->ID;
$nextpost = get_next_post();
$nextid = $nextpost->ID;
$excludearray = array($previd, $thisid, $nextid);

$args = "posts_per_page=4&exclude=$thisid,$previd,$nextid&cat=";
$categories = get_the_category();
$i = 1;
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        $args .= $category->term_id;
    } else {
        $args .= "," . $category->term_id;
    }
    $i++;
}
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()):
    while ($query->have_posts()):
        $query->the_post();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query, and maybe try passing your args in an array.
Above page lists this exact example, which should work:

```
// This WILL work
$exclude_ids = array( 1, 2, 3 );
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => $exclude_ids ) );
```

Comment: But how to use this array as a string, though i have later generating and adding a string to the first query inside foreach.

Comment: That's the thing: you shouldn't use a string. Use one of the category params instead, in your array: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters. Like `category__in`, which expects an array of category IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for guiding me, I just changed the code. Below I am writing my ans.

```
$thisid = get_the_ID();
$prevpost = get_previous_post();
$previd = $prevpost->ID;
$nextpost = get_next_post();
$nextid = $nextpost->ID;
$excludearray = array($previd, $thisid, $nextid);

$exclude_ids = array($previd, $thisid, $nextid);
$args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => 4,
    "post__not_in" => $exclude_ids
);
$categories = get_the_category();
$i = 0;
$cat = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cat[$i] = $category->term_id;
    $i++;
}
$cats = array(
    "category" => $cat
);
$args = array_merge($args, $cats);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()):
    while ($query->have_posts()):
        $query->the_post();
            //Some design stuff.
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) arguments in `WP_Query`. Just use `get_posts()` instead.